# In gem server "rdoc not installed" but have rdoc in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

When I gem server and go to the page, I notice there wasn't a link to the [RDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDoc), and when I move to there a pop out says RDoc is not installed.

But when I type `rdoc --help` in terminal, there is a reply. How to get to the rdoc, because I need to read [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) rdoc?

Comment: what do you mean there wasn't a link to rdoc and when you move to there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by using sudo gem rdoc omniauth ... but nothing inside

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.2 on a Mac and it worked... no rdocs content for omniauth itself but there are docs for oa-basic, oa-core, oa-enterprise, oa-oauth, oa-openid

You can consider uninstalling omni-auth and reinstalling it

```
gem uninstall omniauth
gem install omniauth
```

and see if the rdoc get built.  Also, if you use RVM on Mac or Linux, you can create a new gemset and then install omniauth again and try.

Comment: i solved it with sudo gem rdoc omniauth , but nothing inside .... ohh , so , I want to use the token after oauth , which documentation should i read?